# unique ip visit redirect in php without mysql

Tags: php, arrays, ip, unique, visitor-pattern

i'm sorry if my request seems silly .
i've looked for a long time for this but no luck.
basically what i'm trying to do is : i want when a visitor visits my link'http:/ /mysite. com/redirect .php' , my php script gets his ip address, checks if it exists in an array of ips stored in a file 'hits.txt', if it does then redirect him to another page say'google.com'
if it doesn't then store his ip address in the file then redirect him to another page say 'yahoo.com'.
so later when he comes back to visit again he gets redirected to google.com.
ofcourse my purpose eventually is to make a unique ip visits script.
if you have an idea how to do it without database and sql i'll be grateful, if u think it can only be done with sql then please suggest me the easiest way.
my code so far but it doesn't work :

```
<?php
// Unique Hits PHP Script
// ----------- March 2004
// Contact author: uniquehits@sizzly.com

$log = 'hits.txt';

$IP = getenv (REMOTE_ADDR);
$add = true;
$hits = 0;

if (!file_exists ($log)) {
    echo "Error: $log does not exist.";
    exit;
}

$h = fopen ($log, 'r');



    if (in_array($IP, array($h))){


        header("Location: http://google.com");
    }
        else{
      $fp = fopen('hits.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "'" );
fwrite($fp, $IP );
fwrite($fp, "'" );
fwrite($fp, ',' );
fclose($fp);


        header("Location: http://yahoo.com");

        }





fclose($h);
?>
```

appreciated and thankful to you guys .

Comment: http://pastebin.com/adc6ucZg

Comment: You _do_ know that there is no clear correlation given between a visitor and some IP address? so what sense is there in implementing a logic based on an assumption that does not hold? Many visitors may share the same IP address from your point of view. And a single visitor may use different IP addresses, even at the same time.

Comment: Use a database this will get very slow as the file grows

Comment: well i get my traffic from traffic exchange websites, i want to redirect that traffic,if the ip address has already visited my website then if he comes again i would like to redirect him to another website/page.

Comment: @Dragon, i'm thinking to use cron job, to void the file hits.txt every 24 hours. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use cookies for this.
It's probably a more reliable way than using IP adress, since a lot of people have a dynamic IP anyway.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 1):

thank you , you helped very much, cookies worked very well, much appreciated.
cookies + php :)

here's the code incase someone else would need it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<?php
$IP = getenv (REMOTE_ADDR);
$verifier = "verify";
$cookie_value = $IP;
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$verifier])) {
   setcookie($verifier, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
   header("Location: http://google.com");
} else {
   header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```